# How to find stuff in the kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, reverse-engineering

I'm doing various tasks on the linux kernel, and I end up reading source code from time to time. I haven't really needed to change the kernel yet (I'm good with so called "Loadable Kernel Modules") so I didn't download the source of the kernel, just using http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ . And quite a lot I find myself finding a function that has many implementations, and start guessing which one is the one I need.

For example, I looked at the file [Linux/virt/kvm/kvm_main.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/virt/kvm/kvm_main.c#L496) at line 496 is a call to `list_add`, a click on it gives me two options: `drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/mkregtable.c, line 84` and `include/linux/list.h, line 60` - It's quite clear that kvm will not send my to something under "gpu" but this is not always the case. I have looked at the includes of the file - was not much help.

So my questions: Given a file from the kernel, and a function call at line ###, what is the nicest way to find where one function call actually continues?

(I'll be happy to hear also about ways that don't include the website and\or require me to download the source code)

Comment: *or require me to download the source code* You want to browse the source of the linux kernel without downloading it ? AND without using some lxr site ? I've seen similar requests here http://clientsfromhell.net/

Comment: I do want to use lxr. If it's not possible, I will download the code. I'm also open to any other solution. Just pointed those two out as my first and second preference.

Comment: @Martin I use the http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source site as a first pass.  You can also use C-tags and C-scope to inspect kerne source, search it, etc.  To browse by patch, version, branch, etc., see: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git

Comment: @PeterL. Thanks for the C-tag and C-scope. They look promising.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things in kernel that are `#define`'d or `typedef`'d or functions mapped inside structs (the `fop` struct in the drivers). So, there's no easy way to browse the kernel source. `lxr` site helps you but it can't go any further when you encounter any of the above data structs. The same is with using `cscope/ctags`. The best way though, despite you explicitly mentioning against it, is to download the source and browse through it.

Another method would be to use `kgdb` and inspect the code function by function, but that requires you to have some knowledge of the functions where you want to step in or not, to save a lot of time. And last but not the least, increase the kernel `log` level, and print the logs that are accessible through `dmesg`. But these all require you to have a kernel source.

Comment: LXR and a bit of thinking usually gets the job done. Look at all the definitions found and eliminate the ones that don't make sense.

Comment: Thanks all. It was worth a shot.